# Can't clone nVME ssd drive because it is split into 2 drive paritions?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, gparted, clone

first of all sorry if I do not explain very well or make any mistakes in my syntax.

I want to clone my ubuntu nVME disk but I am having a problem.

I have ubuntu installed on 1 nVME ssd disk when I look at it through GParted I have one 'disk' called '/dev/nvme0n1p2' which is larger and holds all of the data seemingly containing mount points '/' and '/boot/efi' with flags boot,esp and another 'disk' called '/dev/nvme1n1' which is smaller and has a fat32 system-boot with flags boot, lba, and an ext4 writable. These look like the partitions made when creating the Ubuntu install. But in Clonezilla I can only see and clone the smaller of the two of these 'disks' which means I can't get all of the user data which is on my system's disk into the cloned disk.

Thank you kindly for your help!

oldfred has suggested I include the results of `sudo parted -l`

> Model: INTEL HBRPEKNX0202A (nvme) Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB Sector size
> (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: gpt Disk Flags:
>
> Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
> 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot,
> esp  2      538MB   512GB  512GB  ext4
>
> Model: INTEL HBRPEKNX0202AO (nvme) Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 29.3GB Sector
> size (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: msdos Disk Flags:
>
> Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  1
> 1049kB  269MB   268MB   primary  fat32        boot, lba  2      269MB
> 3259MB  2990MB  primary  ext4

And `lsblk -f`:

> NAME    FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL
> FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT loop0   squash
> 0   100% /snap/ardu loop1   squash
> 0   100% /snap/bare loop2   squash
> 0   100% /snap/emac loop3   squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop4   squash
> 0   100% /snap/clio loop5   squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop6   squash
> 0   100% /snap/draw loop7   squash
> 0   100% /snap/disc loop8   squash
> 0   100% /snap/gtk- loop9   squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop10  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop11  squash
> 0   100% /snap/draw loop12  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kde- loop13  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gtk- loop14  squash
> 0   100% /snap/inte loop15  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kde- loop16  squash
> 0   100% /snap/emac loop17  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop18  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop19  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop20  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop21  squash
> 0   100% /snap/core loop22  squash
> 0   100% /snap/disc loop23  squash
> 0   100% /snap/cano loop24  squash
> 0   100% /snap/code loop25  squash
> 0   100% /snap/clio loop26  squash
> 0   100% /snap/cano loop27  squash
> 0   100% /snap/ardu loop28  squash
> 0   100% /snap/code loop30  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kde- loop31  squash
> 0   100% /snap/onsh loop32  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kde- loop33  squash
> 0   100% /snap/pych loop34  squash
> 0   100% /snap/typo loop35  squash
> 0   100% /snap/snap loop36  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kf5- loop37  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gtk2 loop38  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kf5- loop39  squash
> 0   100% /snap/pych loop40  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop41  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kf5- loop42  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kmag loop43  squash
> 0   100% /snap/obs- loop44  squash
> 0   100% /snap/wine loop45  squash
> 0   100% /snap/slac loop46  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop47  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop48  squash
> 0   100% /snap/wps- loop49  squash
> 0   100% /snap/pint loop50  squash
> 0   100% /snap/snap loop51  squash
> 0   100% /snap/spot loop52  squash
> 0   100% /snap/netb loop53  squash
> 0   100% /snap/wine loop54  squash
> 0   100% /snap/spot loop55  squash
> 0   100% /snap/netb loop56  squash
> 0   100% /snap/pint loop57  squash
> 0   100% /snap/upno loop58  squash
> 0   100% /snap/snap loop59  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop60  squash
> 0   100% /snap/krit loop61  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kmag loop62  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop63  squash
> 0   100% /snap/krit loop64  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop65  squash
> 0   100% /snap/qalc loop66  squash
> 0   100% /snap/inte loop67  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kf5- loop68  squash
> 0   100% /snap/magn loop69  squash
> 0   100% /snap/slac loop70  squash
> 0   100% /snap/magn loop71  squash
> 0   100% /snap/mini loop72  squash
> 0   100% /snap/snap loop73  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kde- loop74  squash
> 0   100% /snap/gnom loop75  squash
> 0   100% /snap/typo loop76  squash
> 0   100% /snap/kf5- loop78  squash
> 0   100% /snap/qalc loop79  squash
> 0   100% /snap/upno nvme0n1
> ├─nvme0n1p1 │       vfat            EF9D-C0AB
> 504.9M     1% /boot/efi └─nvme0n1p2
> ext4            9591560d-d226-4922-9bdf-5b28fd6f4d76  197.2G    53% / nvme1n1 isw_ra
> ├─nvme1n1p1 │       vfat   system-boot │
> 4D3B-86C0                                            └─nvme1n1p2
> ext4   writable 79af43d1-801b-4c28-81d5-724c930bcc83

Comment: Do not confuse "disks" with partitions, that is how Windows users get mixed up. Post this in question above, from your system or a live Ubuntu installer. `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk -f`

Comment: Hi oldfred, thank you very much for your help. :) I have included the requested information above in the original post.

Comment: Loops do not matter as those are your snap apps. You are using the very old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Newer gpt has been the standard for over 10 years and is recommended for UEFI boot. I would not clone, but create new gpt partition table, reinstall & restore from your backups.